# Java9, javac --add-exports java.xml.ws/javax.xml.ws=ALL-UNNAMED warning: [options] module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.ws

Tags: java

I have made a little test project where I use `javax.xml.ws.Holder`
The package has been moved to module `java.xml.ws`

```
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
    javac \
     --add-exports java.xml.ws/javax.xml.ws=ALL-UNNAMED \
     --add-exports java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED \
     -sourcepath src/main/java @target/sources.txt -d target/classes
```

This gives compiler warning

```
warning: [options] module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.ws
```

You can also see `--add-exports` java.management it works fine.
I have tried to add-exports of all modules in java9
The modules below gets problems.
I had a hobby theory that it was because the module was @Deprecated (seems not to hold)

```
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.ws                    @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.activation                @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.corba                     @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.jnlp                      NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.se.ee                     NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.smartcardio               NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.transaction               @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.bind                  @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.ws.annotation         @Deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: javafx.deploy                  NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.charsets                   NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.crypto.cryptoki            NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.crypto.ec                  NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.deploy                     NOT deprecated
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.deploy.controlpanel
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.editpad
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.hotspot.agent
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.incubator.httpclient
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.internal.vm.ci
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.javaws
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.jcmd
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.jstatd
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.localedata
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.naming.dns
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.naming.rmi
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.pack
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.plugin
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.plugin.server
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.policytool
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.rmic
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.snmp
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.xml.bind
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.xml.ws
# module name in --add-exports option not found: jdk.zipfs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
warning: [options] module name in --add-exports option not found: java.xml.ws
```

You see this error because there is no java.xml.ws module. Correct module name is java.xml. So your command should be:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
javac \
 --add-exports java.xml/javax.xml.ws=ALL-UNNAMED \
 --add-exports java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED \
 -sourcepath src/main/java @target/sources.txt -d target/classes
```